# C: Comparing 2 strings from file using a structure

Tags: c, file, struct

Currently i am learning about structures and files, and i have been tasked to create a program that will get a string input, and a number input. the program will then go ahead and open up a random database, and find the specific line asked, and check if the string is equal.
Text file:

```
Billy
bob
james
peter
mike
kieran
obidiah
scarlett
john
chloe
sarah
leon
david
andrew
shawn
hannah
phoebe
chris
mark
```

Here is my (I am guessing, incorrect) approach to this program:

(How it should work: Input: james , 3. Ouput:Match)

```
 *FILE *fp;
 int main(void)
 {
   struct store
   {
     char def[128];
   }stock[10];

   int count;
   char string[64];

   printf("Enter the string: ");
   scanf("%s",&string);

   printf("Enter the line: ");
   scanf("%d",&count);

   fp=fopen("Names.txt","r");
   fscanf(fp,"%127[^\n]%*c", stock[count].def);
   if (strcmp(stock[count].def,string)==0)
   {
     printf("Match");
   }
   else
   {
     printf("Nope");
   }
   fclose(fp); 
   getch();
 }
```

This complies just fine, but the program will not read the value in the file.
Anyone know how to get this working?

I use windows and the DEV C complier.

Comment: please read http://sscce.org ... Could you give a *working* example of our code, and make it easy to read (hint: use indentation).

Comment: You want to repeat for, or like while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo:

```
*FILE *fp;
```

Should be:

```
FILE *fp;
```

And arguments of `scanf` are expected to be pointers, but `string` is already (decays into) a pointer.

```
scanf("%s",&string);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%s",string);
```

Comment: @user3227362 Did you check functions return values?, they usually tell you if something went wrong.